# MVC Routing with different Areas with multiple controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My solution structure is the following:

```
Areas
    - Games
        -Controllers
        -Views etc
    - Movies
        -Controllers
            - MoviesController.cs
            - MovieCalendarController.cs
            - MovieSearchController.cs
        -Views etc
```

Now what I would like is to be able to do this:
Navigate to https://localhost/Movies/ and hit the index of the `MoviesController.cs`

Navigate to: https://localhost/Movies/Calendar/ and hit the index of the `MovieCalendarController.cs`

And lastly navigate to https://localhost/Movies/Search/ and hit the index of the `MovieSearchController.cs`

What I have tried but is not working (getting `No route in the route table matches the supplied values.`) errors:

**MovieAreaRegistration.cs**

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Movies_default",
                "Movies/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Movies", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            context.MapRoute(
                "Calendar_default",
                "Movies/Calendar/",
                new { controller = "MovieCalendar", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );


            context.MapRoute(
                "Search_default",
                 "Movies/Search/{action}/{id}",
                    new { controller = "MovieSearch", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Apologies, I'm new to areas and routing

**Update**

After using attribute routing I have fell into this problem:

> Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can
>   happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested
>   URL.
>
> The request has found the following matching controller types: 
>   MovieCalendar.UI.Areas.Movies.Controllers.MovieCalendarController
>   MovieCalendar.UI.Areas.Movies.Controllers.MoviesController

**Movies Controller**

```
[RouteArea("Movies")]
[Route("{action}")]
public class MoviesController : BaseController
{
}
```

**Calendar Controller**

```
[RouteArea("Movies")]
[RoutePrefix("Calendar")]
[Route("{action=Index}")]
public class MovieCalendarController : BaseController
{
}
```

This happens when accessing the url http://localhost/Movies/Calendar hoping it will take me to the `MovieCalendarController` Index action method. I can see why it's complaining because there could be a ActionMethod in the `MovieController` called `Calendar` (There is not).

Comment: Did you run something like this in your global.asax Application_Start?  Areas.MVC.MVCAreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()   where Areas.MVC.MVCAreaRegistration is the namespace to YOUR RegisterAreas method?

Comment: the MovieAreaRegistration was scaffolding code created by Visual Studio. Under the Movies areas folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be better off with *Attribute Routing*. It will let you do this:

```
   public class MoviesController : Controller {

        [Route("Movies")]
        public ActionResult Index() {
            return this.View();
        }
    }

    public class MovieCalendarController : Controller {

        [Route("Movies/Calendar")]
        public ActionResult Index() {
            return this.View();
        }
    }
```

And then you can get rid of your current *route* mappings and use this initialize your routes:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

More information on attribute routing can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx).

**Update**

```
[RouteArea("Movies")]
[Route("{action}")]
public class MoviesController : BaseController
{
}
```

This route will match urls starting with *Movies/* followed by any string, including *Calendar*. So this route will clash with:

```
[RouteArea("Movies")]
[RoutePrefix("Calendar")]
[Route("{action=Index}")]
public class MovieCalendarController : BaseController
{
}
```

Convention based routing will be difficult with the naming convention your are using for your controllers.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me. I just keep getting 404's. I've added the `MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` into my `RouteConfig.cs` too...

Comment: I have updated my question with the issue I am facing