# MVC5(Asp.Net4.5.2)- RedirectToAction does'nt return in one case

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

in my Account controller, in login action, have the code below:

```
                case "Sucess":
                    string rule = CheckRule(model.username, model.Password);
                    Response.SetCookie(SetAuthCookie(model.username, model.RememberMe, rule));
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", rule);
```

In checkrule, i return string with names of another controllers, among them are Admin and BasicUser, here are the codes of these:

```
{
[Authorize]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private bool attAuthor = isAuthorized();
    private bool attAuth = isAuthenticated();
    private string rule = returnrule();
    // GET: Admin
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (!attAuthor)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("erro401",rule);
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }


    }

    public ActionResult erro401()
    {
        return View("erro401");
    }
```

}

and:

```
{
[Authorize]
public class BasicUserController : Controller
{
    private bool attAuthor = isAuthorized();
    private bool attAuth = isAuthenticated();
    private string rule = returnrule();
    // GET: BasicUser
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
         if (!attAuthor)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("erro401", rule);
        }
        else
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authticket = get_ticket();
            string str = rule + " / " + authticket.Name;
            ViewBag.Htmlstr = str;
            return View();
        }


    }

    public ActionResult erro401()
    {
        return View("erro401");
    }


}
```

}

In the RouteConfig:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "",
           defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "BasicUser",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "BasicUser", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Admin",
             url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
         );
```

If I log in with an admin user it works perfectly, but with a basic user the navagador does not redirect to the route, simply is the logon screen, if I enter the controller address works.
I added a tag html to view the cookie userdata and this works fine(show de BasicUserRule).

Sorry if my question is not very clear, i am newbie...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your routes:

1. I don't suggest mapping "" to login. That is actually the homepage. Mapping homepage to login doesn't make much sense. Your login page should be requested automatically when you return an `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized` response from any page, attribute. If you want your homepage only accessed by authorized users, return Unauthorized response from Homepage too. That would be it.

   It's a very good idea read more about how MVC (routing, controllers, authentication, authorization) works. Otherwise you might end up with an app far from secure. StackOverflow is good about solving individual issues but doesn't help you see the big picture. You still need to understand how stuff works.
2. When you have exact same two patterns next to each other, only the first would be matched because MVC stops when it finds a match. Your default values don't help there. Instead, you need to define patterns like:

   ```
   "Admin/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Admin" } 
   "Basic/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Basic" }
   ```

   so, if the URL starts with "Basic", Admin wouldn't be matched or vice versa.

You can use [Route Debugger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/) to understand how route matching works and how your requests get mapped to routes.

Comment: Hi Sedat, thanks for answer, i'll fix these routes, but the `HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized`, where i can configure  this automatic response for Account login? I put the login url in FormsAuthentication on Web.config : `<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="\Account\Login.cshtml"... `

Comment: @RogérioFerreira that should be enough. that is the default behavior. you can also use `[Authorize]` attribute (instead of dealing with HTTP results) if you want to force a login to a before an action.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Sedat!

My troubles were the routes, i set de route with controller in url parameter:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "BasicUser",
                url: "BasicUser/{action}/",
                defaults: new { controller = "BasicUser", action = "Index" }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                 name: "Admin",
                 url: "Admin/{action}/",
                 defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index"}
             );
```

This solved everything.
I followed his advice, and sought a little more information, here are some interesting links:

[MVC Routing with different Areas with multiple controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521396/mvc-routing-with-different-areas-with-multiple-controllers)

[Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641783/Customizing-Routes-in-ASP-NET-MVC)

[(PT-BR)trabalhando-com-rotas-no-aspnet-mvc.aspx](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3059/trabalhando-com-rotas-no-aspnet-mvc.aspx)

Comment: I see other solucions for my application, and I will have to redo some things.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your MapRoutes are not needed because you te simply redirecting to a view. Because both MapRoutes hace the same structure, it will keep only the last one which is Admin.